# Syntax PHP to CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm learning CodeIgniter framework. I have difficulty in PHP to convert the script from CodeIgniter.

How to write a script that I made the change to CodeIgniter?

Here's the code that I have done so far:

```
<?php 
    date_default_timezone_set('Asia');
    $u = $row->jadwalkal;
    $tgl1 = $u;
    $tgl2 = date("Y-m-d");
    $selisih = strtotime($tgl1) -  strtotime($tgl2);
    $hari = $selisih/(60*60*24);
    if ($hari < 0){
    ?>
    <div class="label label-danger"><?php echo "Telat $hari  hari";?></div>
    <?php
    }elseif ($hari < 7) {
    ?>
    <div class="error message"><?php echo "Tinggal $hari hari";?></div>
    <?php
    }else{
    ?>
    <div class="error message"><?php echo "Masih $hari hari";?></div>
    <?php }
?>
```

Comment: Exactly what are you looking for?

Comment: You need to refer user guide http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/

Comment: @rahul,  Yes, that is true ,...

Comment: @DishaV. Thank you but I still do not understand the writing php dicodeigniter

Comment: Well, you have to study but still here is link for you where you can convert your php form into codeigniter code standards https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/form_helper.html

Answer (score 2):

[Codeigniter](https://www.codeigniter.com/) is built by [PHP](https://www.php.net/). So, there's no such work as conversion.

However, You can do some good practises available in Codeigniter to make your code look like Native Codes of Codeigniter which utilises helpers.

Here's the good way to start from [here](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/)

Coming to your question

I would suggest you to pass those values from the Controller to the views like this

```
$data = array(
    'value' => $row->jadwalkal,
    'someotherkey' => 'someothervalue',
);

$this->load->view('results_view', $data);
```

And inside the view i would do the conditions like [this](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/alternative_php.html)

You can retrieve the values that is passed form the controller by

```
echo $value;
```

The Operation shall look like this from your view

**Here's the Clear Syntax**

```
<?php if ($username == 'sally'): ?>

   <h3>Hi Sally</h3>

<?php elseif ($username == 'joe'): ?>

   <h3>Hi Joe</h3>

<?php else: ?>

   <h3>Hi unknown user</h3>

<?php endif; ?>
```

**Here's the conversion for you ;)**

```
<?php if ($value < 0): ?>
<div class="label label-danger"><?php echo "Telat $hari  hari";?></div>
<?php elseif ($value < 7): ?>
<div class="error message"><?php echo "Tinggal $hari hari";?></div>
<?php else: ?>
<div class="error message"><?php echo "Masih $hari hari";?></div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

**Note :**

I have given a simple example to use `if .. else` operations

You shall modify according to your need.

Comment: thanks @Sulthan Allaudeen,  I already know the plot , but there was an error on  $selisih = strtotime($tgl1) - strtotime($tgl2);

Comment: You want the result in seconds ?

Comment: You shall also do `echo round((strtotime($tgl2) - strtotime($tgl1))/3600, 1);` to make it simple ;)

Answer (score 1):

In your case you must use the Controller And View.. Declare all your variables in your Controller something like this here's the sample:

Controller: main.ph

```
class Main extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Manila');
    }

    public function sample()
    {
       $u = date("Y-m-d"); //I just make sample value here
       $tgl1 = $u;
       $tgl2 = date("Y-m-d");
       $selisih = strtotime($tgl1) -  strtotime($tgl2);
       $data['hari'] = $selisih / (60*60*24);    

       $this->load->view('sample',$data)       
    }
}
```

View: sample.php

```
    if ($hari < 0){

       echo '<div class="label label-danger">Telat '. $hari .' hari</div>';

   }else if($hari < 7) {

       echo '<div class="error message">Tinggal '. $hari. ' hari</div>';

   }else{

       echo '<div class="error message">Masih '. $hari . 'hari</div>';
   }
```

Comment: thanks @user5666946,  i can understand the script you wrote , but there is an error in the script  $selisih = strtotime($tgl1) -  strtotime($tgl2); 
Message: strtotime() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

Comment: can I see the value you put in  strtotime()

Comment: ok i get $u from model, $u = $this->mcrud->getDate(); this script 
   `public function getDate(){ 
 $this->db->where('jadwalkal');
 $query = $this->db->get('tbdetail');  
    return $query->result(); 
    }`

Comment: This return $query->result() returns array list. Change it to this return $query->rows()->column_name;

Comment: sorry it's only $query->row()->jadwalkal; hehe

Comment: some error :( , if i try `$u = date("Y-m-d");  $tgl1 = $u;` its work but i change $u load from model its not work...

Comment: Can I see the value you're trying to get from your table.

Comment: i using type 'DATE' this value '2015-08-01'

Comment: what is the error? after you get the return value in the getDate. do this $colValue = $this->mcrud->getDate(); then strtotime($colValue).

Comment: this error message `

Message: strtotime() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

Filename: controllers/dashboard.php

Line Number: 21'

Comment: public function sampleX()
    {
        $u = $this->getDate();
        
        foreach($u as $timeValue)
        {
            $tgl1 = $timeValue->sample; 
            $tgl2 = date("Y-m-d");
            $selisih = strtotime($tgl1) -  strtotime($tgl2);
            $data[] = $selisih / (60*60*24);    
        }
        
        $data['hari'] = count($data);
        $this->load->view('sample',$data)  ;
        
    }
    public function getDate()
    {
        $query = $this->db->get('sample'); 
        return $query->result(); 
    }

Comment: hello @user5666946  , nice this work but appears a zero value `0 hari` , there is one more error in the `$data[' hari'] = count ($data ) ;`message error  `Message : Undefined variable : Data` on count($data )